# Is Fortran a multiple dispatch programming language?

Tags: fortran, multiple-dispatch

Does the `INTERFACE` statement in Fortran make it a programming language officially implementing [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch)? (I ask because the Wikipedia article linked does not feature Fortran among its seemingly comprehensive listing of example programming languages supporting the paradigm in question).

Comment: The `interface` block has many independent uses in Fortran. Which one in particular so you have in mind? How do you want to use it to implement multiple dispatch?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I've seen examples where naming the interface block allows you to call any function within the block by the interface name instead of the function name. In such a case, the compiler presumably determines which function within the block is being called by the number of arguments entered and their type instead of its name within the block.

Comment: As I write in my answer, this is exactly the same like generics in C++, completely compile-time static dispatch. No multiple dispatch. Perhaps check https://lukasatkinson.de/2016/dynamic-vs-static-dispatch/ or some siimilar introducrory resource.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interface blocks (introduced by the `interface` keyword) are often used for generic interfaces. They work like C++ generics, no dynamic dispatch. You must distinguish static dispatch and dynamic dispatch. Both Fortran and C++ only have single dynamic dispatch by polymorphism using classes and inheritance/overloading.

But interface blocks themselves have several independent kinds of usage in Fortran and only some deal with some kind of overloading. Often they just work like a function declaration in a C++ header.

Take the example from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-overloading-c/ :

```
void add(int a, int b)
{
  cout << "sum = " << (a + b);
}
 
void add(double a, double b)
{
    cout << endl << "sum = " << (a + b);
}
```

In Fortran you can do the same but instead declaring both subroutines with the same name straight away, you define two specific subroutines with a different name and make a generic interface for them

```
interface add
  procedure add_ints
  procedure add_doubles
end interface

...

subroutine add_ints(a, b)
  integer :: a, b
  print *, "sum = ", (a + b)
end subroutine
 
subroutine add_doubles(a, b)
  double precision :: a, b
  print *, "sum = ", (a + b)
end subroutine
```

This is the good old static dispatch.

Comment: So if a programming language allows for [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading), the method of dispatch can either be _static_ (during compile-time) or _dynamic_ (during run-time) along with _single_ or _multiple_? In Fortran's case it allows for _static-multiple-dispatch_ via the `interface` statement and _dynamic-single-dispatch_ via its object orientate programming (OOP) facilities? I fail to see the strict resemblance between Fortran `interface`-ing and [C++ generic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming#Templates_in_C++).

Comment: More or less yes. There is no Fortran `interface`ing as such, interface blocks serve several purposes. Fortran generics defined using *generic (named) interface blocks* are the same as static function overloading in C++. C++ generic programming is a much broader topic and includes templates and metaprogrmming - neither of which are available in Fortran. Some C++ programmers will also use templates where ordinary function overloading suffices, but what I was refering to was the ordinary function overloading only, no templates.

Comment: I think I fully understand now. The article linked in my question ([multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch)) refers to the special case where "dispatching" the generic function (_dynamically_) occurs during run-time. And because Fortran achieves this (_statically_) only during compile time it doesn't appear listed in the article as an example. So a better title of that Wikipedia entry would've been _dynamic dispatch_ with with the inclusion of the _single dispatch_  case in a subsection apart from _multiple dispatch_.